# Showing that a set of points equidistant to two other points form a plane.

Tags: calculus, cross-product

Question: if p and q are two distinct points in space, show that the set of points equidistant from p and q form a plane.

Work Done:

Note: I'm pretty sure this can be done with vectors and cross products, but in any case this is what I did:  I believe I can solve it this way, but it looks quite tedious.

My idea is that I can make a triangle with the origin, p, and the point below/above p on the x / y plane (z component = 0).  I do the same with q, and thus have to triangles.  Then, I can note the angle between the two triangles by making a triangle with points p, q, and the origin.  From the angles I have so far, I believe that I'd be able to find the angle of the plane formed (I think I can also do this through cross product?) and then would be able to rotate the plane extended through the line r(t) according to this angle.  However, I can't imagine that this is the way we're wanted to do this... Is the cross product / unit vector idea correct?  Thanks.

Comment: Because we already know it is a plane, an approach would be to: 1. prove that any point $X$ in that plane is equidistant to $P$ and $Q$.  2. prove that a point not in that plane is not equidistant.

Answer (score 1):

Just expand
$$\|x-p\|^2=\|x-q\|^2$$
to achieve an equation of the plane nearly instantaneously.